# cmake Qt5 failes with "module QtQuick is not installed'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I have tried a simple Qt Qml example and I am not able to build it. I already googled and found a dozen similar problems, but none of the recommendations helped me. My code looks like this:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Minimal Qml")
}
```

qml.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Qml Quick REQUIRED)

qt5_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES qml.qrc)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(PROJECT "qmltest")
project(${PROJECT})

add_executable(${PROJECT} main.cpp  ${QT_RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT}
    Qt5::WinMain
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
)
```

I used windeployqt to get all librarys into the right place. The programm starts on my Windows machine but the console output ends with:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

Path to the app after deploying it:

```
<DIR>   bearer
            qgenericbearerd.dll
<DIR>   iconengines
            qsvgicond.dll
<DIR>   imageformats
            qgifd.dll
            qicnsd.dll
            qicod.dll
            qjpegd.dll
            qsvgd.dll
            qtgad.dll
            qtiffd.dll
            qwbmpd.dll
            qwebpd.dll
<DIR>   platforminputcontexts
            qtvirtualkeyboardplugind.dll
<DIR>   platforms
            qwindowsd.dll
<DIR>   qmltooling
            qmldbg_debuggerd.dll
            qmldbg_inspectord.dll
            qmldbg_locald.dll
            qmldbg_messagesd.dll
            qmldbg_natived.dll
            qmldbg_nativedebuggerd.dll
            qmldbg_previewd.dll
            qmldbg_profilerd.dll
            qmldbg_quickprofilerd.dll
            qmldbg_serverd.dll
            qmldbg_tcpd.dll
<DIR>   scenegraph
            qsgd3d12backendd.dll
<DIR>   styles
            qwindowsvistastyled.dll
<DIR>   translations
            ...
<DIR>   virtualkeyboard
            qtvirtualkeyboard_hanguld.dll
            qtvirtualkeyboard_openwnnd.dll
            qtvirtualkeyboard_pinyind.dll
            qtvirtualkeyboard_tcimed.dll
            qtvirtualkeyboard_thaid.dll
        concrt140d.dll
        d3dcompiler_47.dll
        libEGLd.dll
        libGLESv2d.dll
        msvcp140d.dll
        msvcp140d_atomic_wait.dll
        msvcp140d_codecvt_ids.dll
        msvcp140_1d.dll
        msvcp140_2d.dll
        qmltest.exe
        qmltest.ilk
        qmltest.pdb
        Qt5Cored.dll
        Qt5Guid.dll
        Qt5Networkd.dll
        Qt5Qmld.dll
        Qt5Quickd.dll
        Qt5Svgd.dll
        Qt5Widgetsd.dll
        vccorlib140d.dll
        vcruntime140d.dll
```

I'm using Qt 5.15 open source. I built it and installed it on WIndows7.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What is `QtQuick.Controls 1.2`? My Qt docs recommends `import QtQuick.Controls 2.15`

Comment: @folibis I got it from an example and thought it would be backward compatible. I switched both to 2.15 but it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Because it's windows, sometimes you can fix things by ensuring that (1) you run the executable from the same working directory as the libraries, (2) update the PATH environment variable, and/or (3) deploy a `qt.conf` configuration

Comment: @StephenQuan All libraries are in the same folder copied by `windeployqt`.

Comment: @Alexander can you include your question in a directory tree, cause, the plugins such as QtQuick and QtQuick.Controls must be of a particular directory structure before they can be loaded correctly. A great troubleshooting too is Microsoft SystemInternals ProcMon. Run your application with that running and observe the CreateFile references.

Comment: @StephenQuan updated the tree view. I will try to dig deeper with ProcMon.

Comment: @StephenQuan all Qt libs are loaded from the deploy path. Nothing suspicious found with ProcMon. :(

Comment: @Alexander that is the contents of the plugins folder above, but where are your qml components? i.e. qml, qml/Qt, qml/QtQuick, qml/QtQuick.2, etc. ProcMon should be showing that it's attempting to load qml components but encountering file not found.

Comment: @StephenQuan in my ProcMon logs only this could not be load: api-ms-win-core-....DLL, qtlogging.ini, flatpak-info, main.qmlc (NAME INVALID). Which files should be in the qms dirs? Where can I find them to copy them manually?

Comment: @StephenQuan And I get this Warning from windeployqt: Warning: Cannot find Visual Studio installation directory, VCINSTALLDIR is not set. Unsure if this has an influence?

Comment: I have confused by your question. As you mention you cannot build but you also use windeployQt which step is not needed with the build/compile you should able to run the app inside QtCreator without doing any things with windeployQt. from your deploy directory is also weird because all  Qt lib list there are debugged mode lib.

Answer (score 1):

For one of our Windows app, we deploy over 1700 files. The directory structure looks roughly like this:

```
<DIR> MyQtApp_Bin_Dir
          MyQtApp.exe
          COPY C:\Qt\Qt5.15.6\5.15.6\msvc2019_64\bin\*.dll
          COPY C:\Qt\Qt5.15.6\5.15.6\msvc2019_64\resources\*.*
          COPY C:\Qt\Qt5.15.6\5.15.6\msvc2019_64\plugins\*
          COPY VISUALSTUDIO_REDISTRIBUTABLES_HERE

<DIR> MyQtApp_Bin_Dir\qml
          COPY C:\Qt\Qt5.15.6\5.15.6\msvc2019_64\qml\*
```

In the directory dump that you posted, the `qml` folder appears to be absent. The content directly controls the `import` statements that you are having issue with.

Comment: Thank you! With copying qml\\* it works now!